Why does entering decimal numbers in the input fields result in zero?
I have a form tag in HTML that has three inputes fields. Basically I want the oninput function to do a simple multiplication for me, but when I enter a decimal number, it gives me zero. For all other numbers it works.
Here is my code


 <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(b.value)*parseInt(c.value) + '&nbsp Cubic feet'">
  <label for="a">Width (ft)</label> &nbsp
  <input type="number" id="a" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="b" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="c" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="total"> The total valume of your concrete area is : </label>
  <output name="x" for="a b c"></output>
</form>`




What gives 0? The final result? Is your decimal 0.X? Because you parse it to int so this will be 0 after parsing. (And everything multiplication times 0 gives obviously 0).

Probably you parsed to the wrong data type. If you want to work with decimals, use parseFloat. Else use a ceil before parsing to get 1.
With floats


<form oninput="x.value=parseFloat(a.value)*parseFloat(b.value)*parseFloat(c.value) + '&nbsp Cubic feet'">
  <label for="a">Width (ft)</label> &nbsp
  <input type="number" id="a" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="b" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="c" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="total"> The total valume of your concrete area is : </label>
  <output name="x" for="a b c"></output>
</form>`



With ceil ( I would not know why but just in case :) )


 <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(Math.ceil(a.value))*parseInt(Math.ceil(b.value))*parseInt(Math.ceil(c.value)) + '&nbsp Cubic feet'">
  <label for="a">Width (ft)</label> &nbsp
  <input type="number" id="a" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="b">Length (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="b" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="c">Height (ft)</label>
  <input type="number" id="c" value="any"><br><br>
  <label for="total"> The total valume of your concrete area is : </label>
  <output name="x" for="a b c"></output>
</form>




Might need to add step size attribute
step="0.1"  

to the input
